# Email Image Instead of Saving - Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, email, webcam, contact-form-7

I am trying to make a webcam plugin compatible with contact form 7.

This code allows me to save the webcam image directly to the gallery.

```
add_action('init','web_cam_form_submittion');
function web_cam_form_submittion(){
    if(isset($_POST['web_cam_submit']))
    {
        $img = sanitize_text_field($_POST['image']);
        if($_POST['slug']){
            $slug = sanitize_text_field($_POST['slug']);
        }
        else{
            $slug = "";
        }
        $base = dirname(__FILE__);
        $folderPath = $base."/upload/";

        $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
        $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
        $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
      
        $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
        $fileName = uniqid() . '.png';
      
        $file_before_upload = $folderPath . $fileName;
        file_put_contents($file_before_upload, $image_base64);

        $image_url = $file_before_upload;

        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

        $image_data = file_get_contents( $image_url );

        $filename = basename( $image_url );
        if ( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
            $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
        }
        else {
            $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
        }
        file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );
        $attachment = array(
          'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
          'post_title' => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
          'post_content' => '',
          'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );

        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file );

        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
        unlink($file_before_upload);
        if(has_action("web_cam_media_id")){
           do_action("web_cam_media_id",array("media_id"=>$attach_id,"slug" =>$slug));
        }
        
    }
    else{
        return '';
    }
}
```

What I want to do is that the image captured when I submit the form is sent to me as an e-mail (attachment-file).

How can I achieve this? I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This is contact form 7?

Comment: This is webcam plugin built for wordpress. This code allows the webcam image to be saved in the gallery.

Comment: Your question says "Contact Form 7" and you are using the tag `contact-form-7` - so this is not for Contact form 7 - right?  It's just some other kind of form.

Comment: What I want to do is have the webcam image come to me via contact form 7 via email.